# Compound interest with varying compounding frequency

Tags: algorithms

Here is the problem I have attempted to solve.

> Given original principal $n$ and aggregate rate $r$, find the maximum final principal that can be yielded.

Though I know that the higher the compounding frequency is, the higher the final principal will be, a special condition applies:

> Intermediate principals are rounded down to the the nearest integer each time.

So for example $n = 10000$ and $r = 3$, I can choose to have

- 1% growth 3 times
- a 2% growth then a 1% growth
- or a 3% growth.

For case 1 n would grow as 10000 -> 10100 -> 10201 -> 10303.

For case 2 n would grow as 10000 -> 10200 -> 10302.

For case 3 n would grow as 10000 -> 10300.

So in this case the highest value would be 10303.

As another example, take $n = 10$ and $r = 10$. As it will not yield any changes to $n$ unless the growth rate is higher than 10%, the answer is 11.

So in mathematical terms it is to find $\max n\prod(1+r_i\%)$ where $\sum r_i = r$ with the rounding condition.

What I was trying to do is to find the minimum growth rate that would result in a change in $n$ and apply it immediately, then repeat the process until $r$ is used up, but it doesn't seem that it is getting the desired answer. Any hints would be appreciated. If you need any clarification please tell me.

```
    while(r > 0 && rate < r){
        rate++;
        if (n * (100 + rate) / 100 != n){
            n = n * (100 + rate) / 100;
            r -= rate;
            rate = 0;
        }
    }
```

$r_i$ must be positive integers.
This problem is adapted from A028:武器の強化 problem, which can be found [here](https://paiza.jp/challenges/ranks/a/info) (on paiza, which is a Japanese-language coding contest site).

Comment: Thanks!  I've edited the question to incorporate that information.  In the future, please edit the question rather than leaving a comment (and don't use "EDIT:"; we have history to see what has changed).  I've done it for you this time, but letting you know so you can do it yourself in the future.

Comment: Your proposed strategy seems natural to me too.  Can you list the simplest counterexample where your proposed strategy is not optimal, and what is the optimal solution and the solution your strategy achieves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a good example of problems that can be solved by [dynamic programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info).

Given original principal $n$, the subproblems are, what is $p(t)$ for $0\le t\le r$, the maximum final principal that can be yielded if aggregate rate is $t$ . We have the following recurrence relation, where $//$ means the integer division, for example, $13 \operatorname{//} 5 = 2$.

$$p(t) = \max( p(0) + p(0)* t \operatorname{//} 100,\ p(1)+p(1) * (t-1) \operatorname{//} 100,\ p(2)+ p(2) * (t-2) \operatorname{//}100,\ \cdots,\ p(t-1)+ p(t-1) * 1 \operatorname{//} 100)
$$

From $p(0)=p$ you can compute $p(1)$. From $p(0)$ and $p(1)$, you can compute $p(2)$. And so on. Finally you can will get $p(r)$, which is what you want.

I will left you figure out the actual implementation. By the way, the code in question, fails when the original principal is 23 and the aggregate rate r is 9.

Comment: Sounds like it is similar to brute force method that is optimized, but I will give it a try! Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, this is NOT brute force at all. This is about the fastest approach one can get. You should compute the recurrence relation iteratively as said in the answer. There should be no problem for any average implementation to pass all tests. Good luck!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. I guess it scans and determines the optimal value for each stage before proceeding for higher values of t based on the values computed beforehand. I stored p(t) in an array and didn't use any recursion though. Not sure if I implemented it correctly as it got 8/10 test cases correct.

Comment: Your understanding seems correct. You made a bug in implementation, though. What is your result for p=23 and r =9? Also, you should use java long just in case the result overflows java int.

Comment: Yes the problem is caused by overflow. Oh god thank you for your wonderful answer.